# Take different parts of an image for the background of two divs

Tags: html, css

At https://es.ikariam.gameforge.com/, three boats appear at the bottom of the page. Inspecting the elements with devtools reveals that they belong to different divs with unique IDs, as follows from left to right:

`div#ship-2`, `div#ship-1` and `div#submarine`

Of note, all the divs share the same picture for their [backgrounds](https://gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnb1/12ae07bab9d5fd778d5234c27f4d87.png),  taking in each case a different part/slice of it.

How may I implement this using CSS?

Comment: I think what you are after is how to implement CSS sprites. you can read about how to implement and why [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). It mainly has to do with strongly defining heights and widths of an object then setting the correct `background-position` for the sprite background. You can use a site like [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com/) to help you generate the correct CSS for your sprite.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, **not only on a separate site**. once you get your answer, you'll update that site, and then this question will be of no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique with respect to the three boats involves creating a [CSS sprite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) which in this particular case entails code manipulating the height, width, bottom and left or right properties of the given image.  You may detect that information yourself by using the "Inspect" feature of your browser which reveals the following CSS code for each vessel, as follows:

```
#ship-1 {
    background: url(//gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnb1/12ae07bab9d5fd778d5234c27f4d87.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 192px;
    width: 345px;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}

#ship-2 {
    background: url(//gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnb1/12ae07bab9d5fd778d5234c27f4d87.png) no-repeat -346px 0;
    height: 224px;
    width: 280px;
    bottom: 6%;
    left: 0;
}

#submarine {
    background: url(//gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnb1/12ae07bab9d5fd778d5234c27f4d87.png) no-repeat -626px 0;
    height: 174px;
    width: 260px;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 0;
}
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4ntnoa6q/2/)